# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' ,having this error when i try to filer my data by column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

**I am having some trouble , I have folder of txt files and read file from folder one by one and process. in my code i read file from folder and then save file in df and when i try to filter data based on column i got this error.(Note: if i save this df again in computer and load again and try to filter then no error), please of any one can mention where i am doing wrong **

Here is my df 
[image]

My code:

```
for file in os.listdir('csv/'):

    filename = 'csv/{}'.format(file)

    print(filename)

    df = pd.read_table(filename,skiprows=3,sep=';')

    df1=df.loc[(df['#timestamp'] <= 0) & (df['#timestamp'] >=-5)]
```

Here is exact error message

[image]

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: It looks like your timestamp were read as `'str'`, you should convert the value to `'float'` first before doing the comparison. [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) may help in your case.

Comment: @peter leimbigler , I added exact error details please check